# Laravel session is implemented, but the session value is not stored in local web browser's cookies

Tags: laravel, session, cookies

I'm currently working in a Laravel8 local environment.
I added a part to generate a session in the login API code, but there's an issue. When the login API is called from the web browser, generated session value is stored in the local 'storage/sessions' file. Also the cookie value is properly included in the response cookies. However, it is not stored in the application's cookies.

Below are the settings I've made.

**api.php**
`Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->middleware('session');`

**.env**

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=60
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SESSION_SAME_SITE=lax
```

**AuthController.php**

```php
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->en) {
            $request->password = $request->password;
            $request->merge([
                'email' => $request->email,
            ]);
        }

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'    => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if (!$user = User::where('email', PetraCommon::encrypt($request->email))->first()) {
            return response()->error(1002, 404);
        }
        $login_log = $this::getFailLog($user->idx);
        if ($login_log && $login_log->count > 5) {
            if ($login_log->reject_period < 5) {
                return response()->error(1022, 401);
            } else {
                $login_log->delete();
            }
        }

        if (!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            $this::setFailLog($user->idx);
            return response()->error(1000, 401);
        }

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt(['email' => PetraCommon::encrypt($request->email), 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $this::setFailLog($user->idx);
            return response()->error(1000, 401);
        }

        if ($request->undormancy) {
            $user_dormancy = 0;
        } else {
            $user_dormancy = User::selectRaw("case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, connected_at, now()) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as dormancy")
                ->find($user->idx)->dormancy ?? 0;
        }

        if (($user_dormancy ?? 0) < 1) {
            $user->connected_at = DB::raw('now()');
        }

        $user->save();

        if ($request->undormancy) {
            PointCommon::setPoint('1100', $user->idx);
        }

        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->dormancy = $user_dormancy ?? 0;

        if (!$user->dormancy) {
            $user->token = $token;
        } else {
            $user->token = null;
            PointCommon::dormancyPoint($user->idx);
        }

        $user->temporary_password = 0;
        if (PasswordReset::where('email', $user->email)->exists()) {
            $user->temporary_password = 1;
        }
        if (UserLoginFailLog::where('user_idx', $user->idx)->exists()) {
            UserLoginFailLog::where('user_idx', $user->idx)->delete();
        }

        if ($user->profile_image_url) {
            $user->profile_image_url = config('filesystems.cdn_url') . $user->profile_image_url;
        }
        $user->over_password_date = User::selectRaw("
            case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, password_at, now()) > 90 then 1 else 0 end as password_term
        ")->find($user->idx)
            ->password_term ?? 0;
        $user->password_regist = 1;

        UserLoginLog::create([
            'user_idx' => $user->idx,
            'login_type' => 'email',
            'action' => 'login'
        ]);
        request()->session()->put('key', 'value');
        return response()->success($user);
    }
```

**session.php**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('laravel', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    'http_only' => false,

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

In the http environment, the cookie value may not be stored, so SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE was falsely processed, and SESSION_DOMAIN declared 'localhost'. However, it still does not store session values in web browser cookies.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cookies to be saved on the user's browser, you need to change your configuration in the .env file

change the SESSION_DRIVER to cookie instead of file

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=60
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SESSION_SAME_SITE=lax
```

if this helps you solve the problem, you can upvote this and mark as the correct answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
However, even if you change SESSION_DRIVER to cookie, it still appears only in response cookies, and it is not saved in the cookie of the application.

Comment: It will save it in the browser cookies under the application section in developer mode

Comment: I checked again and it still doesn't save in cookies. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you update your code with the login code you omitted ? you can update the login method with full code in your initial question

Comment: I have updated the entire login code you mentioned. Currently implemented code is token authentication, but for security reasons, it needs to be changed to session authentication.